# Is there a program that handles text background well?

Tags: text, background

Paint is the best I've found until now. I need the ability to add a background to text and also control padding. Paint would be perfect if it didn't squeeze text to the left and made equal padding from top and bottom.

I know I could add some spaces in front and to edit height of the container, but I'm planning to do editing for hundreds of pages and it's impractical to tweak the box size for every piece of text

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4pOn.png]

Comment: This text tool option is merely for highlighting single words or sentences within a block of running text. To create a text box with a colored background, you need to draw a box and place the text above it (e.g. using layers) or, if available, use a text frame tool.

Comment: @TehMacDawg I have scanned pages of text which include hand written parts. Single words as well as sentences. They are poorly visible, so I want to replace that hand written text with "digital" text and background. Of course it's possible with layers, but it would take too much time

Comment: I think a little more information would be good. How layers would take more time mystifies me. I would say quite contrary. Are you digitalising the text or do you just want to superimpose it on an image with transparency? Paint is generally not the best tool, but your margin-padding problems should simply be a question of placing the text box.

Comment: @boblet I uploaded a video for you of 3mins comparing how fast can I put labels with PS vs paint http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2psgjti%3E&s=5#.UpsHAcQmk08

Answer (score 2):

I would use InDesign.

Create a new document the size of your images and import each scan in a page. 
Make a text frame with the colors you want. Go in Object Styles and right-click on basic text frame to redefine its style. All your text frames will be the same now.

Some other advantages:

- You can control the size of the text frame right off the bat (paint seems to give a certain width at first instead of letting you drag to the desired size.
- You can go back and edit anytime, it is non-destructive.
- You can change the color of all the items at once by editing the basic text frame style
- When you're done, export a PDF to have your whole document in one file
- If you do your changes on a layer, you can easily turn them off to review the original document.

Hope this helps!